# Are there any blockchain implementations that are not based on the Bitcoin source code?

Tags: blockchain, source-code

I wanted to code up a blockchain from scratch using C++. So I got around to looking at some existing blockchain source code to get some ideas. But all I can find is the Bitcoin source or forks of it.

Are there any blockchain implementations out there that are not based on the Bitcoin source code?

Comment: Ethereum and EOS jump to mind as largely independent codebases.